# Continuity sets are neccesary for weak convergence.

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

[Portmanteau theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures)

In particular if $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly then $\mu_n(A)\to \mu(A)$ for each continuity set. I want an example to show that the hypothesis of $\mu(\partial(A))=0$ is neccesary.

I need to know an example involving probability measures. I tried to contruct an example but I failed.

I don't know why this proof is incorrect:

$\mu_n(A)=\int{1_Ad\mu_n}\to \int{1_Ad\mu}=\mu(A) $

Comment: Let $\mu_n$ be a normally distributed probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Let $\mu$ be the point mass (also known as the Dirac measure) at $0$. Then $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly. Notice that $\mu_n(\{0\})=0$ for all $n$, but $\mu(\{0\})=1$. Thus $\mu_n(\{0\})$ does not converge to $\mu(\{0\})$.

Comment: @Shalop Why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your attempt is that $\mathbf 1_A$ is not continuous in general, hence we cannot use the definition of weak convergence.

However, defining $\mu_n:=n\mathbf 1_{(0,1/n]}\lambda$, that is, $\mu_n(A)=n\lambda(A\cap (0,1/n])$, we have that $\mu_n\to\delta_0$ weakly, $\mu_n(\{0\})=0$ for each $n$ but $\delta_0(\{0\})=1$.